# How to do FEM in sector elements?

Tags: finite-element, basis-set

Suppose we have an element in the polar coordinate as $0\leq r\leq 1$, $0\leq\theta\leq \alpha$. What are the correct basis functions in this element?  For this kind of mesh, there
are a lot of references on finite difference discretization. But I can not find a fem solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct basis functions"? There are an infinite number of bases that could be used to expand the solution in such an element.

Comment: I tried to use the function basis which is linear in $r, \theta$. But I found I can not put d.o.f. at the origin point $r=0$ and the two vertices $r=1,\theta=0,\alpha$. If $\varphi=ar+b\theta+c$, and $\varphi(0,\theta)=0$ for any $\theta$, then $b=c=0$.

Comment: You could consider using isoparametric curvilinear elements with the nodes distributed using the warp & blend procedure do to T. Warburton suitable for explicit (read efficient) construction of interpolation nodes on the simplex (http://www.caam.rice.edu/~timwar/preprints/JEMnodesV1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for answering and pointed out the reference. But by using isoparametric elements, do you mean the sector boundary will only be approximated in cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ by polynomials? Is there any way to keep exactly the shape of the sector?

Comment: Yes. The use of isoparametric elements means approximation of the boundary by polynomials of the same order as the polynomials used in the element basis. Also, it is should not be important whether you represent you boundary exactly or not, since you commit approximation errors anyways. What is important is that you you through the approximation procedure have the possibility to reduce truncation errors.

Comment: That's true the error can be diminished by refinement. My question actually comes from the following observation in FEM references. There is a Laplace equation defined on a disk with a hole at the center, or we just call the domain annulus.  Then, the polar coordinate elements $0<r_1\leq r\leq r_2, \theta_1\leq\theta\leq\theta_2$ are well-defined. But no books or papers study the problem on the full disk without a hole. In the latter case, one encounters the sector element with a coordinate collapse at $r=0$.

Comment: If you use rectangular elements, then this is really a tough question. If you have a regular $n$-gon in the middle then you might piecewise linear shape functions on that object still (with different gradients on the n-gon) such that continuity is preserved along element edges. Still $r=0$ might be a source of error, and an adaptive strategy is a must-do. - For triangle elements, none of this problems arise.

Comment: Thank you Martin! So your solution is just to remove the node at r=0 and put n-nodes r=1, θ=θ1,…,θn on the center disk element. This **preserves exactly the geometry**. Good idea! But if I use a linear function in θ as linear nodal basis at one node, I got multi-values at r=0!